# nafxcw.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dll_dllmain_stub.obj)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a DLL project I am compiling on Visual Studio 2022 that is importing a lib from created by another project. When I try to compile this code, I receive this: nafxcw.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dll_dllmain_stub.obj). I have looked everywhere, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works.

I have tried adding these libc.lib, msvcrt.lib, libcd.lib, libcmtd.lib, msvcrtd.lib to the ignore libraries list.

I tried adding extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; } to the DLLMain in the file from the imported library that has the redefined DLLMain, but this leads to an error saying that __afxForceUSRDLL has been defined twice.

Any and all help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I imagine the library you're linking to is a static library and uses a different visual studio runtime to your dll. You can't mix vs runtimes within a dll

Comment: Second the comment above, you have to match the compilation options used in your project so that they match the options that were used in the library you are statically linking with. Such are the drawbacks of static linking.

Comment: Most probably you are mixing compile/link options. What options was that "other project" built with? There are quite a few to check: debug/non-debug, unicode/non-unicode, multithreaded/multithreaded-DLL, statically-linking-MFC/shared-MFC... (forgot sth?). You rather need to rebuild the project that produced the static (import?) library you are using, with the same options. Pls check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-170).